# Are there any hidden changes if I change a numpy array that is a reference for another variable?

Tags: python, numpy

this is just a question purely out of interest.
I was learning numpy when I stumbled upon the difference between assigning an existing array to a variable and using numpy.copy().

```
import numpy as np

original = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
new = original[:, 0]
original[2, 2] = 69
print (new)
```

```
[ 1 4 7 10]
```

I know that if changes are made to the existing array (`original`), `new` will also have the same changes. But if I change something in `original` that is out of bounds for `new`, nothing will be changed in `new`. My question is, are there any hidden changes in `new` if this happens? Should I be concerned?

Comment: `new` is just a view of `original`. It shares the same data. If you change the data that is in view, then you change `new`. if not then you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`original[:, 0]` is a **view** on `original`. This means that both share the same memory buffer containing array values. Modifying one will affect the other. Technically, `original` is also a view and in Numpy you can never really manipulate array, only view on arrays. Numpy take care of the memory management of array for you. A view is a reference to an array, some offsets, some strides, a size and some low-level flags. Not much more. **Modifying a values of an array using a view does not affect the other view objects themselves** though the content of the views can be affected since they reference the same array (technically, view does not contain the values, only "hidden" referenced array).

Put is shortly: no, there is no other hidden change than the modified cell in the shared array.

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on what you would mean with "hidden" changes. What you have done when you assigned a part of `original` to `new` is that you made a view. Only that what is within your "scope" of `new` is changed. Underlying nothing changes that. As soon as you get into the "scope" of `new` inside `original`, you will start seeing changes reflected when you use `new`. Note, however, that `new` is not changed under the hood, because you look at a view.